# Variable and module with same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

Is it possible to import module **app** from package **src** when that package's **__init__.py** contains variable of the same name as module:

```
.
├── run.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── app.py
```

**__init__.py**:

```
app = "variable"
```

**run.py**:

```
from src import app
```

Comment: I think this would work, if `app` variable was in **app.py** module, but in my example it's in **\_\_init_\_.py**.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question

Comment: Can you use __ all __ in __ init __.py?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean, but when I set `__all__ = ["app"]`, then still the variable is exported.

Answer (score 1):

Python tends to be relatively picky about its variable names and namespaces. I would heavily recommend changing the name of the variable to something else, if possible.